# Turning a time series back into a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

Firstly, apologies for what is probably a very easy question. I have been following an example to plot STL and have come up with a nice line chart. I would like to extract the data points so I can use them in Tableau in this format:

[image]

(sorry, having trouble getting tables to display)

My time series is generated from a count in the same format as the table above, so I assume it is quite simple to stitch it back together, but I am not very experienced with data manipulation in R yet. I am happy with the actual seasonal plot, it's just the matter of tying it all back up into something I can use.

I cannot provide my data, but I can provide the following from a tutorial which does the same thing:

```
library(xts)
## load co2 data set
load(url("https://userpage.fu-berlin.de/soga/300/30100_data_sets/KeelingCurve.Rdata"))

library(lubridate)
start <- c(year(xts::first(co2)), month(xts::first(co2)))
start

end <- c(year(xts::last(co2)), month(xts::last(co2)))
end

# creation of a ts object
co2 <- ts(data = as.vector(coredata(co2)),
          start = start,
          end = end, frequency = 12)

# set up stl function
fit <- stl(co2, s.window = "periodic")
```

I am able to extract the list of y-axis values using:

```
seasonal_stl <- fit$time.series[,1]
```

What I would like to do is reconstruct that into a table of Month, Year and the seasonal value. Can anyone suggest how to do that? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: James, could you post the demo data using DPUT please? Many users are reluctant to download files. Often people will use data sets included with R to demo the problem, eg `data(package = "tsibble")`
bank_calls and souvenirs have dates

Run `dput`, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tsibble` package to convert the ts object into a data frame in the form you want.

```r
ts(fit$time.series, start=start, frequency=12) |> 
  tsibble::as_tsibble() |> 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "key", values_from = "value") |> 
  tibble::as_tibble()
```

But you might find it easier to use the `tsibble` and `feasts` packages from the start, like this.

```r
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)
library(lubridate)

## load co2 data set
load(url("https://userpage.fu-berlin.de/soga/300/30100_data_sets/KeelingCurve.Rdata"))
start <- c(year(xts::first(co2)), month(xts::first(co2)))

# creation of a tsibble object
co2 <- ts(co2, start=start, frequency=12) |> 
  as_tsibble()

# Fit STL
fit <- co2 |> 
  model(stl = STL(value ~ season(window = "periodic")))

# Extract components
components(fit)
#> # A dable: 711 x 7 [1M]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#> # :        value = trend + season_year + remainder
#>    .model    index value trend season_year remainder season_adjust
#>    <chr>     <mth> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 stl    1958 Mar  316.  315.       1.46   -0.551            314.
#>  2 stl    1958 Apr  317.  315.       2.59   -0.0506           315.
#>  3 stl    1958 May  318.  315.       3.00   -0.514            315.
#>  4 stl    1958 Jun  317.  315.       2.28   -0.286            315.
#>  5 stl    1958 Jul  316.  315.       0.668  -0.00184          315.
#>  6 stl    1958 Aug  315.  315.      -1.48    1.13             316.
#>  7 stl    1958 Sep  313.  315.      -3.16    1.01             316.
#>  8 stl    1958 Oct  313.  315.      -3.25    0.468            316.
#>  9 stl    1958 Nov  313.  316.      -2.05   -0.148            315.
#> 10 stl    1958 Dec  315.  316.      -0.860  -0.0377           316.
#> # … with 701 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>